# Error during make: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to compile some code downloaded from a git repository (OpenNI2, https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2). I am getting the following errors after running make:

```
make -C Source/Tools/NiViewer
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/karnivaurus/Data/Libraries/OpenNI2/Source/Tools/NiViewer'
g++ -o ../../../Bin/x64-Release/NiViewer ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/Device.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/Draw.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/Keyboard.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/Menu.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/MouseInput.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/NiViewer.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x64-Release/NiViewer/Capture.o -L../../../ThirdParty/PSCommon/XnLib/Bin/x64-Release -L../../../Bin/x64-Release -lglut -lGL -lOpenNI2 -lXnLib -Wl,-rpath ./
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../ThirdParty/PSCommon/XnLib/Bin/x64-Release/libXnLib.a(XnLinuxMutex.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../Bin/x64-Release/NiViewer] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/karnivaurus/Data/Libraries/OpenNI2/Source/Tools/NiViewer'
make: *** [Source/Tools/NiViewer] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how I should go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the directive "-lpthread" to your compiler and it is solved.

for instance if your previous code was:
g++ mycode.cpp -o myexecutable

Now you have to put
g++ mycode.cpp -lpthread -o myexecutable

Answer (score 0):

You need add the pthread library into the target_link_libraries. You can edit your CMakeLists.txt file as follow. This solution works for me.

```
    target_link_libraries(ExcutableFileName ${Existed_LIBRARY})
    -->
    target_link_libraries(ExcutableFileName ${Existed_LIBRARY} pthread)
```